# the variable in $.ajax() function giving undefined value outside the function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a web page using html5 . the problem is I am taking a json from a url and printing its result on console. I am getting the expected result in the function but not getting it outside it. even if the variable is global. please see the following code

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://192.168.1.5:3333/abc.json',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            //var result = $(this).html(JSON.stringify(data));
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(result); // Result : 1
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });

   console.log("here::"+result); // Result : 2
});
</script>
```

I am getting result as

```
    2  here:undefined
    1    object                     (json)
```

I need this json for parsing.

Comment: Hmm, `async: false` and `dataType: 'jsonp'` seem conflicting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear about this:

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.

Basically, that means your `async: false` is not being used at all, which explains the behaviour.

See also: [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: so you mean to say I cannot use the json in javascript now and if I can then how....

Comment: @shark You can use `jsonp`, no problem; but you just have to use asynchronous.

Comment: could you please tell me how with some example ... I am a newbie..

Comment: @shark You're already using asynchronous because you have a `success` handler ... put whatever things you need to do when the request is finished in there.

Comment: how could I know when the request is finished...

Comment: @shark The fact that your success handler is called is indicative of that.